# What is an elegant way to add n adjacent rows in a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

For example, for a matrix:

```
A = [1 2; 
     3 4; 
     5 6; 
     7 8; 
     9 10; 
     11 12]
```

the output would be

```
B = [4 6; 
     12 14; 
     20 22]
```

if I sum every two adjacent rows in the matrix.

ps: it would be a plus if also the function works on column vectors to sum n adjacent entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `reshape` and `sum`:

```
k = 2; % how many elements to sum
n = size(A,1)/k;
out = reshape(A, k, n, []);
out = sum(out, 1);
out = reshape(out, n, []);
```

Of course, `n` must be an integer. That is, the height of the matrix must be evenly divisible by `k`.

This will work for any number of columns, including a Nx1 matrix (==column vector).

(I wrote this out in separate lines to make it clearer what is happening, but of course you can turn this into a one-liner if you're so inclined.)

Comment: This is the answer to use if you can assume the exact divisibility and you want something _fast_ (ref my [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005779/3978545))

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution using [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html). It works even if `n` does not divide the number of rows of `A` (the last group will then be smaller). The key is to create a vector of integers defining the groups (last input of `splitapply`).

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10; 11 12; 13 14]; % 7 rows
n = 2; % number of adjacent rows to add
B = splitapply(@(x) sum(x,1), A, ceil((1:size(A,1))/n).');
```

results in

```
A =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
     9    10
    11    12
    13    14
B =
     4     6
    12    14
    20    22
    13    14
```

Answer (score 3):

Both solutions work perfectly. I also came up with another way using accumarray, in case you are interested.

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10; 11 12];
n = 2;
index = repelem(1:size(A, 1)/n, n).';
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) accumarray(index, A(:, x)), 1:size(A, 2),'UniformOutput', false));
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, **you could just use a loop**

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10; 11 12];
n = 2;

sz = size(A);
B = NaN( ceil(sz(1)/n), sz(2) ); % initialise output
for ii = 1:size(B,1)                     % Loop over rows of output
    B(ii,:) = sum( A( (ii-1)*n+1:ii*n, : ) ); % Assign sum for the relevant rows
end
```

This could work even if `n` did not exactly divide the number of rows in A (the final group would use fewer rows) if you capped the upper index `(ii-1)*n+1:min(sz(1),ii*n)`

---

**I've added a benchmarking script below for the 4 existing answers**

- I'm slightly surprised how slow [Luis' `splittapply` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77003099/3978545) is for large inputs.
- Although the use of `cell2mat` makes it look a bit clunky, the [self-answer by the_wicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005533/3978545) is very fast.
- Perhaps because `reshape` is almost "free" on computation, [Cris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77002535/3978545) is lightning fast, although it does have the drawback of assuming `n` evenly divides the number of rows.
- My method above is middling on speed, so maybe shows that loops aren't catastrophically slow, and viable if you just need to get something working.
- If the number of rows in each group is within a couple of orders of magnitude of the rows in the input, i.e. the output is only hundreds of rows, then all of the methods are very quick anyway.

**Results**

```
wolfie (loop): 0.426sec
the_wicked (accumarray): 0.099sec
cris (reshape & sum): 0.009sec
luis (splitapply): 3.430sec
```

**Code**

```
A = rand(1e6,10)*100;
n = 2;

%% Ensure the outputs are equivalent
w = wolfie(A,n);
intol = @(a,b) max( abs( a(:) - b(:) ) ) < 1e-8;
assert( intol( w, the_wicked(A,n) ) );
assert( intol( w, cris(A,n) ) );
assert( intol( w, luis(A,n) ) );

% Timing with output to command window
fprintf( 'wolfie (loop): %.3fsec\n', timeit( @() wolfie(A,n) ) );
fprintf( 'the_wicked (accumarray): %.3fsec\n', timeit( @() the_wicked(A,n) ) );
fprintf( 'cris (reshape & sum): %.3fsec\n', timeit( @() cris(A,n) ) );
fprintf( 'luis (splitapply): %.3fsec\n', timeit( @() luis(A,n) ) );

% Functions from answers as of 2023/08/30 08:41
function B = wolfie( A, n )
    B = NaN( ceil(size(A,1)/n), size(A,2) ); % initialise output
    for ii = 1:size(B,1)
        B(ii,:) = sum( A( (ii-1)*n+1:ii*n, : ) );
    end
end
function B = the_wicked( A, n )
    index = repelem(1:size(A, 1)/n, n).';
    B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) accumarray(index, A(:, x)), 1:size(A, 2),'UniformOutput', false));
end
function out = cris( A, k )
    n = size(A,1)/k;
    out = reshape(A, k, n, []);
    out = sum(out, 1);
    out = reshape(out, n, []);
end
function B = luis( A, n )
    B = splitapply(@(x) sum(x,1), A, ceil((1:size(A,1))/n).');
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking; it is quite insightful. 
Anyway, based on my limited experience with MATLAB, any MATLAB function that can handle categorical data, as well as numerical data, is quite slow compared to other functions that work only on numerical data. I recall that the function "groupcounts" also was not that fast compared to other alternatives.

Comment: Interestingly `splitapply` is "open" to view, so it can be profiled. It looks like indeed all of the generic way to handle different variables are the big overhead, namely the way it loops through the rows to "split" the data. Other than that, it actually uses `accumarray` under the hood on each variable to do the aggregation step.